# How do I set the <img src from with out specifying the extension in a razor view?

Tags: razor, model-view-controller

I have an MVC app that has a logo image that is in my Images folder. The file name is always "egs_logo_small" but it could be a .png or a .jpg or a .gif etc...
I want to simply set my

```
           @{ 
                var dir = Server.MapPath("~/Images/");
                string path = Path.Combine(dir + "egs_logo_small.*");
                var filename = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path).First();
                string image = "/images/" + filename;
            }

            <img src=@image style="backface-visibility: hidden" />
```

How can this be done?

Comment: I think your question needs clarification but from what I can see you're going down the filename road, while you should be looking for the image's url, that will serve the extension of the image in the end, too.

Answer (score 0):

In my case there will always be 1 image file named "logo" that could have any extension. I was able to resolve this on my own by doing this:

```
@{
                string filename = "";
                string image = "";
                var dir = Server.MapPath("~/Images/");
                string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(dir, "logo.*", System.IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
                if (files.Length > 0)
                {
                    filename = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(dir, "logo.*").First();
                    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(filename);
                    image = "/images/logo" + fi.Extension;
                    <img src=@image style="backface-visibility: hidden" />
                }

            }
```